# Can't insert into a database using sqlite3_bind_text

Tags: c, sqlite

Hello I have an issue with this function `recup()`. The purpose of `recup()` is to insert all of the words found in the string `chaine`, word by word, into a database. The words come from chaine which is set by the user using a fgets. The problem I am facing is that it is only inserting words that have the same length as the first word of `chaine`.
For example, if I write  "I want a cat", only "I" and "a" will be inserted.

```
int recup(char *chaine){

    char tab[30] ={0};
    char delim[] = " ";
    char *ptr = strtok(chaine,delim);

    int rc =0;
    char *sql ="INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM dbTable where lemme =?";

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = 0;

    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,sql,-1,&stmt,0); 

    do {
        // Expected word is printed here
        printf("%s\n",ptr);
        strcpy(tab,ptr);

        // For some reason, only words that match the length
        // of the first word are being inserted
        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,1,tab,-1,SQLITE_STATIC);  
        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        ptr = strtok(NULL,delim);
    } while(ptr != NULL);
    rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt); 
    return 0;
}


#include <ansi_c.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include "fdata.h"
sqlite3 *db;   

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
      int rc = 0;
      char chaine[100] = {0};
      rc = sqlite3_open("lexique.db",&db);
      check(rc);
      createNewT();
      question(&chaine);
      recup(&chaine);
      sqlite3_close(db); 
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function as part of your  [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.

Comment: Hmm..., you never test the `rc` return value. It is bad not to do it, and very bad to not even print it when things go wrong. And anyway, why do you use that strange SQL statement if you just want to insert words from the input text?

Comment: You're right I should check rc. I need this SQL statement to use a variable in the where.

Comment: You should use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` instead of `SQLITE_STATIC` in your call to `sqlite3_bind_text`. Perhaps it's related to the problems you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C SQLite API is not very tolerant, and requires strict semantics. Here your problem is that you try to reuse a SQL statement in a loop (which is right) without resetting it (which is wrong). The current flow is:

```
sqlite3_open
sqlite3_prepare_v2
sqlite3_bind
sqlite3_step
sqlite3_bind => ERROR SQLITE_MISUSE
```

While the documentation for `sqlite3_step` says (emphasize mine):

> SQLITE_DONE means that the statement has finished executing successfully. **sqlite3_step() should not be called again on this virtual machine without first calling sqlite3_reset()** to reset the virtual machine back to its initial state.

I assume that the following `sqlite3_step` causes a statement reset, which will allow the 3rd word to be processed, but you lose every second word.

The loop should be:

```
do {
    printf("%s\n",ptr);
    strcpy(tab,ptr);


    rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,1,tab,-1,SQLITE_STATIC);
    if (rc) {
        // process error
    }
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        // process error
    }
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
    ptr = strtok(NULL,delim);
} while(ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how to use `strtok` to tokenize your example string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *test = "I want a cat";
    char chaime[strlen(test) + 1];
    char *delim = " ";
    char *ptr = NULL;

    strcpy(chaime, test);
    ptr = strtok(chaime, delim);
    while (ptr) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
[user@machine]: ./program
I
want
a
cat
```

**Note**

If you can give us something like this that demonstrates your problem, it will make it easier to help you.

Comment: In my program the printf of ptr match what I should have but once I check the result in my database only the words with the same length as the first word have been inserted.

Answer (score 1):

The strtok() function modifies the string that is passed into it.  So, it is necessary to create a copy of the input string.  See @David Cullen's excellent answer which creates a mcve.

See the comments in the corrected code that explain what is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int recup(char *chaine){


  char tab[30] ={0};
  char delim[] = " ";
  ///// strtok will modify its inut string argument, so create a copy of the input
  strcpy(tab, chaine);
  // ptr will contain the current last token that was parsed
  char *ptr = strtok(tab,delim); // pass the copy to strtok, ptr points to first word

  int rc =0;
  char *sql ="INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM dbTable where lemme =?";

  sqlite3_stmt *stmt = 0;

  rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,sql,-1,&stmt,0);


  while (ptr) {
    printf("%s\n",ptr);  // print the word that was just tokenized

    rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,1,ptr,-1,SQLITE_STATIC);
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    ptr = strtok(NULL,delim);
  }
  rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  return 0;
}
```